# Why won't supervisor D work on Laravel Sail?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, debugging, laravel-sail

Anyone else having trouble using supervisor D with Laravel Sail?  I didn't think it'd be this painful.  I'm following the doc info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#configuring-supervisor) but it's not as straightforward as it seems.

Even after all configurations being set, I get an error that says `error: <class 'FileNotFoundError'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 560` upon running `supervisorctl reread` while SSH'd into the Sail shell.

I've tried all the suggestions shown [here](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/491) but to no avail.  I've hit a wall on this and unsure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after you installed supervisor, there was a problem with your python installation package. You may need to reinstall supervisor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).